# Jquery validation for .asp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp-classic

I am trying to have a checkboxes validation using Javascript, and i am really not sure how to apply this code that i found it working..if the page is in .html it works fine but if it is in .asp the validation doesnot work but i want to make it work using jquery validation this is the checkbox code that i have now

```
 $<input type="checkbox" name="entry.9.group" validate="required:true, minlength:2" value="Bank Transfer" id="group_9_1" />
  Bank Transfer ()<br />
  <input class="required" type="checkbox" name="entry.9.group" value="Call &amp; Collect" id="group_9_2" />
  Call me on my mobile (STS will call you in before end of the day)<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.9.group" value="Others" id="group_9_3"/>
  Others<br />
```

These are the .js files that i added to my header

```
   <script src="js/jquery _2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.metadata _2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and i am unsure how to get these two to work? tks..btw if it helps i am collecting the data from the form to google spreadsheets that is why you are seeing the name="entry.9.group"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i realised that i have to use the C# inbuilt validation rather than the Java validation. If i do want to use java vlaidation in case then its better to stick to HTML

Comment: not "java validation" but "javascript validation" and whether it's .html or .asp or .fubar doesn't matter to the browser, so long as the content is text/html or text/xhtml, it will display as HTML in the browser. There is likely something else wrong when it's generated as .asp (and nowadays you should try to migrate away from .asp when doing new code, as much as possible, altho I recognize not everyone has that luxury of choice)